# IBM MQ JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'MY_LOCAL_QM' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'MY_LOCAL_QM(1401)'

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I created a queue manager, queue, channel(Server-connection).
When I try to send a message, see this error:
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'MY_LOCAL_QM' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'epspa(1401)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.

Maybe I need to set a user to queue manager? Because I use the same java code, but try to connect to another queue manager, and it works fine. But it doesn't work with my queue manager. 
IBM MQ installed on another PC.

```
 private static final String HOST = "epspa";
private static final int PORT = 1401;
private static final String CHANNEL = "API.SVRCONN_LOCAL";
private static final String QMN = "MY_LOCAL_QM";
private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "API.QUEUE_NAME";
private static final String message ="message";

public static String sendMessage(String message) {
    String result = "Error";
    try {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        cf.setHostName(HOST);
        cf.setChannel(CHANNEL);
        cf.setPort(PORT);
        cf.setQueueManager(QMN);
        cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_MQ);

        Destination destination = null;
        MessageProducer producer = null;

        Connection c = cf.createConnection();
        Session s = c.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        destination = s.createQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
        producer = s.createProducer(destination);
        TextMessage tmo = s.createTextMessage();


        ((MQDestination) destination).setMessageBodyStyle
                (WMQConstants.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_MQ);

        tmo.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_CHARACTER_SET, 1208);
        tmo.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_ENCODING,546);
        tmo.setText(message);
        producer.send(tmo);

        result = "Success!";
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you create a listener?   What errors if any do you find in the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG`?

Comment: Hi @JoshMc!
Yes, I created the listener. I can't find this log on Windows. Where it can be found?

Comment: There should be a path where you installed MQ, under that directory it will be `qmgrs\MY_LOCAL_QM\errors\AMQERR01.LOG`.  Did you start the listener or set it with `CONTROL(QMGR)` and restart the queue manager?

Comment: There is no error in AMQERR01.LOG.
AMQ5026: The listener 'LISTENER.TCP' has started. ProcessId(2703).

Comment: Does that listener listen in port 1401?

Comment: What was the problem?   You never replied to me or to Roger.

Answer (score 1):

> cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_MQ);

Well, that's not correct.  It should be:

```
cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
```

> JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager

A JMS error does not give enough details about what MQ is complaining about.  You need to output the LinkedException.

```
catch (JMSException e)
{
   if (e != null)
   {
      System.err.println("getLinkedException()=" + e.getLinkedException());
      System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Are you sure that port # of 1401 is correct?  The default port # for MQ is 1414.  Start runmqsc against your queue manager. i.e.

```
runmqsc MY_LOCAL_QM
```

then issue the following command:

```
DIS LISTENER(LISTENER.TCP)
```

what value is given for the PORT attribute?

> tmo.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_CHARACTER_SET, 1208);
>   tmo.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_ENCODING,546);

Why are you setting the CCSID and Encoding?  Why don't you let JMS & MQ take care of it?

Here is a fully functioning JMS program that puts a message to a queue:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.jms.*;

import com.ibm.mq.jms.*;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

/**
 * Program Name
 *  MQTestJMS11
 *
 * Description
 *  This java JMS class will connect to a remote queue manager and put a message to a queue.
 *
 * Sample Command Line Parameters
 *  -m MQA1 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1414 -c TEST.CHL -q TEST.Q1 -u UserID -x Password
 *
 * @author Roger Lacroix
 */
public class MQTestJMS11
{
   private static final SimpleDateFormat  LOGGER_TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

   private Hashtable<String,String> params;
   private MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQCF = null;


   /**
    * The constructor
    */
   public MQTestJMS11()
   {
      super();
      params = new Hashtable<String,String>();
   }

   /**
    * Make sure the required parameters are present.
    * @return true/false
    */
   private boolean allParamsPresent()
   {
      boolean b = params.containsKey("-h") && params.containsKey("-p") &&
                  params.containsKey("-c") && params.containsKey("-m") &&
                  params.containsKey("-q") &&
                  params.containsKey("-u") && params.containsKey("-x");
      if (b)
      {
         try
         {
            Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p"));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            b = false;
         }
      }

      return b;
   }

   /**
    * Extract the command-line parameters and initialize the MQ variables.
    * @param args
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException
    */
   private void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
      if (args.length > 0 && (args.length % 2) == 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2)
         {
            params.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      if (allParamsPresent())
      {
         try
         {
            mqQCF = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
            mqQCF.setQueueManager((String) params.get("-m"));
            mqQCF.setHostName((String) params.get("-h"));
            mqQCF.setChannel((String) params.get("-c"));
            mqQCF.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            try
            {
               mqQCF.setPort(Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p")));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
               mqQCF.setPort(1414);
            }
         }
         catch (JMSException e)
         {
            if (e != null)
            {
               MQTestJMS11.logger("getLinkedException()=" + e.getLinkedException());
               MQTestJMS11.logger(e.getLocalizedMessage());
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            MQTestJMS11.logger(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         }
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Test the connection to the queue manager.
    * @throws MQException
    */
   private void testConn()
   {
      QueueConnection conn = null;
      QueueSession session = null;
      Queue myQ = null;

      try
      {
         conn = mqQCF.createQueueConnection((String) params.get("-u"), (String) params.get("-x"));
         conn.start();

         session = conn.createQueueSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         MQTestJMS11.logger("successfully connected.");

         myQ = session.createQueue((String) params.get("-q"));

         MQDestination mqd = (MQDestination) myQ;
         mqd.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_JMS_COMPLIANT);
//         mqd.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);

         sendMsg( session, myQ);
      }
      catch (JMSException e)
      {
         if (e != null)
         {
            MQTestJMS11.logger("getLinkedException()=" + e.getLinkedException());
            MQTestJMS11.logger(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         MQTestJMS11.logger(e.getLocalizedMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            if (session != null)
               session.close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MQTestJMS11.logger("session.close() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         }

         try
         {
            if (conn != null)
               conn.stop();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MQTestJMS11.logger("connection.stop() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         }

         try
         {
            if (conn != null)
               conn.close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MQTestJMS11.logger("connection.close() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * Send a message to a queue.
    * @throws MQException
    */
   private void sendMsg(QueueSession session, Queue myQ) throws JMSException
   {
      QueueSender sender = null;

      try
      {
         TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
         msg.setText("Nice simple test. Time in 'ms' is  -> " + System.currentTimeMillis());
         // msg.setJMSReplyTo(tq);
         // msg.setJMSDeliveryMode( DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

         MQTestJMS11.logger("Sending request to " + myQ.getQueueName());
         MQTestJMS11.logger("");

         sender = session.createSender(myQ);
         sender.send(msg);
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            if (sender != null)
               sender.close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MQTestJMS11.logger("sender.close() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * A simple logger method
    * @param data
    */
   public static void logger(String data)
   {
      String className = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();

      // Remove the package info.
      if ( (className != null) && (className.lastIndexOf('.') != -1) )
         className = className.substring(className.lastIndexOf('.')+1);

      System.out.println(LOGGER_TIMESTAMP.format(new Date())+" "+className+": "+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()+": "+data);
   }

   /**
    * mainline
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      MQTestJMS11 write = new MQTestJMS11();

      try
      {
         write.init(args);
         write.testConn();
      }
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
      {
         MQTestJMS11.logger("Usage: java MQTestJMS11 -m QueueManagerName -h host -p port -c channel -q JMS_Queue_Name -u UserID -x Password");
         System.exit(1);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         MQTestJMS11.logger(e.getLocalizedMessage());
         System.exit(1);
      }

      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: For those of you who also feel a lack of colors, here is highlighted version of the same code: https://pastebin.com/wsGyhkJr